Parameter pack to initialize member std::array
I have a class Color which is a thin wrapper around std::array.  I would like to be able to use it in 2 ways:

Color<5> color{1,2,3,4,5} should produce color.values = [1,2,3,4,5]
Color<5> color{3} should produce color.values = [3,3,3,3,3]

What I currently have is:
template <size_t N>
class Color {
public:
    Color() = default;
    Color(std::array<float, N> values) : values{ values } {};

    template <IsNumeric... T>
    Color(T... v) : values{ static_cast<float>(v)... } { };

    ....

private:
    std::array<float, N> values;
}

This works correctly for my first-case.  However for the second case it only produces: color.values = [3,0,0,0,0].  I am at a loss for how to get the second case to work.  I have tried:
template <size_t N>
class Color {
public:
    Color() = default;
    Color(std::array<float, N> values) : values{ values } {};

    template <IsNumeric... T, typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(T) == N), bool>::type = true>
    Color(T... v) : values{ static_cast<float>(v)... } { };

    template <IsNumeric T>
    Color(T v) : values{ std::array<float, N>{ static_cast<float>(v) } } { };

    ...
}

But this does not change anything.

this is how initialization of C style arrays is defined. std::array is just a wrapper around it.

Is IsNumeric a concept?

@康桓瑋 yes IsNumeric is a concept

@MarekR I don't follow what your comment is intending to convey to me.

It means even if your enable_if worked and other constructor is called, std::array<float, N>{ static_cast<float>(v) } would not result in what you expect.

And what should Color<5> color{1, 2, 3} do?

Your values is most probably std::array, so c-arrya initialization rules are applying. When you are passing less arguments then number of elements in c-array remaining elements are default initialized. To overcome this problem: you should provide API which will do std::fill on an array in body of constructor, or your initialization list will do some padding with missing elements.

Offtopic: when I see symbol name Color I expect something which holds RGB values or something similar (CMY HSV) - something with 3 dimensions, so this Color<5> is a bit surprising. It would be nice to know what this Color suppose to do, before posting a good (alternative) solution.

You can do this with the help of std::index_sequence and a helper function. Since you are already using concepts you should use a requires clause to replace std::enable_if.
Your code doesn't show what type the member values is, but the question title as well as the other constructor seems to imply that it is a std::array and that is what I use here. Anyway it should work as long as the type of values has a variadic constructor that does the correct thing.
namespace detail{
    template <std::size_t... Is, typename T>
    constexpr std::array<float, sizeof...(Is)> makeValues(std::index_sequence<Is...>, T v){
        return {((void)Is, v)...};
    }
}

template <size_t N>
class Color {
public:
    constexpr Color() = default;
    //constexpr Color(std::array<float, N> values) : values{ values } {};

    template <IsNumeric... T> requires (sizeof...(T) == N)
    constexpr Color(T... v) : values{ static_cast<float>(v)... } { };

    template <IsNumeric T>
    constexpr Color(T v) : values{detail::makeValues(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, static_cast<float>(v))} { };

    std::array<float, N> values;
};

It can be verified by the following test main function:
int main(){
    static_assert(Color<2>{5,4}.values == std::array<float,2>{5,4});
    static_assert(Color<2>{5}.values == std::array<float,2>{5,5});
    // Color<3> doesntCompile{1,2};
}

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/KGeehW5x6

For types which need "index_sequence" in their interface, I tend to put it as template parameter:
template <typename IntSeq> class ColorImpl;

// Helper for variadic expansion
template <std::size_t, typename T> using always_t = T;

template <size_t... Is>
class ColorImpl<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    std::array<float, sizeof...(Is)> values{};
public:
    constexpr ColorImpl() = default;
    constexpr explicit ColorImpl(std::array<float, sizeof...(Is)> values) : values{ values }
    {}

    // requires to avoid conflicts with default constructor and "fill" constructor
    constexpr ColorImpl(always_t<Is, float>... fs) requires (sizeof...(Is) > 1) :
        values{ fs... }
    {}

    constexpr explicit ColorImpl(float f) : values{ (static_cast<void>(Is), f)... } {}

    // ...
};

template <std::size_t N>
using Color = ColorImpl<std::make_index_sequence<N>>;

Demo

You can have a single constructor using a function fillpad that will fill up to M items into the array (M being the number of items in the initialization list).
In case M<N, you can complete the array with the last value of the list.
#include <array>

template<class T> concept IsNumeric = std::is_arithmetic_v<T>;

template <std::size_t N, IsNumeric...T>
constexpr auto fillpad (T... v) 
{
    static_assert (sizeof...(v) <= N);
    
    std::array<float,N> result {static_cast<float>(v)...};
    
    for (std::size_t i=sizeof...(v); i<N; i++) { result[i] = result[i-1]; }
    
    return result;
}

template <std::size_t N>
struct  Color 
{
    Color() = default;
    
    template <IsNumeric...T>
    constexpr Color(T... v) : values {fillpad<N>(v...)}  {}
    
    std::array<float,N> values;
};

static_assert (Color<5>{1,2,3,4,5}.values == std::array<float,5>{1,2,3,4,5});
static_assert (Color<5>{1,2,3,4}  .values == std::array<float,5>{1,2,3,4,4});
static_assert (Color<5>{1,2,3}    .values == std::array<float,5>{1,2,3,3,3});
static_assert (Color<5>{1,2}      .values == std::array<float,5>{1,2,2,2,2});
static_assert (Color<5>{1}        .values == std::array<float,5>{1,1,1,1,1});

int main() {}

Demo
Note that if you want to enforce that either 1 or N arguments are provided, one can substitute the static_assert in the fillpad function with:
static_assert (sizeof...(v)==1 or sizeof...(v)==N);

